# error: package androidx.core.math does not exist Camera Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have Upgraded my flutter project to 2.2 and also I upgraded my all packages.
here is a problem with camera plugin upgrade. I have tried lots of ways but wasn't helpful.

my  **error** after

> flutter run --release

```
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.8.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\CameraZoom.java:10: error: package androidx.core.math does not exist
        import androidx.core.math.MathUtils;
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.8.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\CameraPermissions.java:12: error: package androidx.core.app does not exist
    im
```

port androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

my **flutter doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1935], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision b22742018b (10 days ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\RAR-Aliryanfox\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\RAR-Aliryanfox\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 51.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\RAR-Aliryanfox\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.22.0


• No issues found!
```

my **packages**

```
 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  introduction_screen: ^2.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^3.0.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  package_info: ^2.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
  another_flushbar: ^1.10.22
  url_launcher: ^6.0.4
  shamsi_date: ^0.14.1
  persian_date: ^0.1.5
  simple_animations: ^3.1.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  encrypt: ^5.0.0
  sms_receiver: ^0.3.1+1
  imei_plugin: ^1.2.0
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.6.9
  permission_handler: ^8.0.0+1
  flutter_qr_reader: 1.0.3
  contact_picker: 0.0.2
  barcode_widget: ^1.5.0
  uni_links: ^0.5.1
  camera: ^0.8.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  path: ^1.8.0
  navigation_history_observer: ^1.1.0
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^6.0.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.1.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.0.0
  device_info: ^2.0.1
  share: ^2.0.1
  contacts_service: ^0.6.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I resolved it with the following change in my code:

**change this**

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 28

  defaultConfig {
     targetSdkVersion 28
  }
}
```

**To**

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 30

  defaultConfig {
     targetSdkVersion 30
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't help :((

Comment: still, have the problem? can you share your Gradle file?

Comment: temporarily I fixed it with changing the build.gradle file of my **contact_picker** package! [Here is explained](https://m.blog.naver.com/chandong83/222017109563)

Comment: @RARGroup in my case it worked using that configuration and without making any other changes.